# What does "base fitness" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, vocabulary, phrases

What does base "fitness" mean in this sentence?

"Exercise helps. And walking can be performed by most of us, without training, equipment, or even a base fitness."

Source: https://positivepsychology.com/mindful-walking/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Anyone who is able to walk can take walks for exercise; you don't have to have a certain level of physical fitness to start doing so.

Comment: The sentence you've quoted would be more commonly expressed as "...or even a base[line] **level of** fitness." I'm not sure why the article omitted "level of," which seems to be the cause of confusion.